# Extract websocket connection Id and other details from websocket in AWS Api Gateway with HTTP integration

Tags: http, websocket, aws-api-gateway

I have an http endpoint `https://websocketsample.free.beeceptor.com`
and an API Gateway in AWS for Websockets with routes for `$connect`, `$disconnect` and `$default`, all of them integrated with HTTP integration to a POST `https://websocketsample.free.beeceptor.com` so that I can capture the http request.

When I test it with wscat

```
wscat -c wss://e96ypxXXXX.execute-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/production
```

I can see the HTTP requests received at the HTTP server (in my case beeceptor). The problem is that $connect and $disconnect don't have any payload in the POST request, only http headers. Example:

- When I $connect to websocket I get

  ```
  Request body: empty
  Headers:
  {
    "content-length": "0",
    "sec-websocket-extensions": "permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits",
    "sec-websocket-key": "pTR36OHKUSk8cqBix8vJXA==",
    "sec-websocket-version": "13",
    "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-605322fb-1e2b058363326df80a61df18",
    "x-forwarded-for": "185.153.165.121",
    "x-forwarded-port": "443",
    "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
    "user-agent": "AmazonAPIGateway_e96ypxXXXX",
    "x-amzn-apigateway-api-id": "e96ypxXXXX"
  }
  ```
- When I send any message to the websocket such as `{"action":"action1"}` I get

  ```
  Request body: {"action":"action1"}
  Headers:
  {
    "content-length": "20",
    "user-agent": "AmazonAPIGateway_e96ypxXXXX",
    "x-amzn-apigateway-api-id": "e96ypxXXXX",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
  }
  ```
- And when I $disconnect the websocket I get

  ```
  Request body: empty
  Headers:
  {
    "content-length": "0",
    "x-api-key": "",
    "x-forwarded-for": "",
    "x-restapi": "",
    "user-agent": "AmazonAPIGateway_e96ypxXXXX",
    "x-amzn-apigateway-api-id": "e96ypxXXXX"
  }
  ```

**How can I get the connection Id so that I can track every websocket session independently?**
When I tested this with lambda, the request had a requestContext where I could extract the connectionId and use DynamoDb to manage connections. **I don't want to use AWS Lambda**, I have already an http back-end service which can deal with this. But HTTP integration does not seem to provide much information.

---

**Update 1**: This article may explain some of the reasons https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/websocket-api-data-mapping.html
Apparently:

"Data mapping for WebSocket APIs isn't supported in the AWS Management Console. You must use the AWS CLI, AWS CloudFormation, or an SDK to configure data mapping."

So it may be that I need to configure data mapping outside the console and hopefully build up a payload that makes sense

---

**Update 2**: I've added request parameters as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/websocket-api-data-mapping.html#websocket-mapping-request-parameters but no luck

```
$ aws --profile diegosasw apigatewayv2 update-integration --integration-id 3lppdXX --api-id oe9jal8gXX --request-parameters 'integration.request.header.connectionId'='context.connectionId'
{
    "ConnectionType": "INTERNET",
    "IntegrationId": "3lppdXX",
    "IntegrationMethod": "POST",
    "IntegrationType": "HTTP_PROXY",
    "IntegrationUri": "https://websocketsample.free.beeceptor.com/connections",
    "PassthroughBehavior": "WHEN_NO_MATCH",
    "PayloadFormatVersion": "1.0",
    "RequestParameters": {
        "integration.request.header.connectionId": "context.connectionId"
    },
    "TimeoutInMillis": 29000
}
```

A connection request still doesn't get forwarded to beeceptor with connectionId in http headers or anywhere and I don't know how to achieve that.

Plus.. I found what it seems an issue in API Gateway API Websocket when creating http endpoints: [Unable to use different HTTP verbs in API Gateway with API Websocket and HTTP integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66707833/unable-to-use-different-http-verbs-in-api-gateway-with-api-websocket-and-http-in)

Not the most intuitive documentation or usage.

---

SOLUTION: As per the marked answer, the solution was as easy as re-deploying the API. The request parameters would be then forwarded properly.

```
"Items": [
        {
            "ConnectionType": "INTERNET",
            "IntegrationId": "okmv0au",
            "IntegrationMethod": "POST",
            "IntegrationType": "HTTP_PROXY",
            "IntegrationUri": "https://awswebsocket.free.beeceptor.com",
            "PassthroughBehavior": "WHEN_NO_MATCH",
            "PayloadFormatVersion": "1.0",
            "RequestParameters": {
                "integration.request.header.domainName": "context.domainName",
                "integration.request.header.stage": "context.stage",
                "integration.request.header.connectionId": "context.connectionId",
                "integration.request.header.messageId": "context.messageId"
            },
            "TimeoutInMillis": 29000
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have most likely forgotten to deploy your API (Routes -> Actions -> Deploy API). WebSocket APIs still use the old console which does not have auto deploy.

It works when I try it

```
        {
            "ConnectionType": "INTERNET",
            "ContentHandlingStrategy": "CONVERT_TO_TEXT",
            "IntegrationId": "iasyqzb",
            "IntegrationMethod": "ANY",
            "IntegrationType": "HTTP_PROXY",
            "IntegrationUri": "[REDACTED]",
            "PassthroughBehavior": "WHEN_NO_MATCH",
            "PayloadFormatVersion": "1.0",
            "RequestParameters": {
                "integration.request.header.connectionId": "context.connectionId"
            },
            "TimeoutInMillis": 29000
        },
```

Headers:

```
connectionid: dL53oem8IAMCK9g=
host: [REDACTED]
sec-websocket-key: dJleaOF55APY+0K6bPJWmg==
sec-websocket-version: 13
user-agent: AmazonAPIGateway_fhyhvnschc
x-amzn-apigateway-api-id: fhyhvnschc
x-amzn-trace-id: Self=1-6067d697-7dc1eea10d51468c3adbbc80;Root=1-6067d697-048e3deb132e05d50553a29e
x-forwarded-for: [REDACTED]
```

Comment: you're absolutely right. I was nearly there but didn't know I had to re-deploy the API after updating the integration. I can now see the connectionId and whichever integration request parameter I set. Thank you